# How to close / delete a Morph in Squeak?

Tags: user-interface, smalltalk, squeak, morphic

Let's say I have a new Morph:

```
m := Morph new.
m openInWorld.
```

How do I close / delete the Morph off?

```
m removeFromWorld.
```

Comment: Try `m world removeMorph: m`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a morph from the world, use the `delete` method.

```
m := Morph new.
m openInWorld.
...
m delete.
```

`delete` removes the morph from its parent morph (which is the world after `openInWorld`).